# Plot multiple dots using ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a table with values that I would like to add as dots to a chart. 
A simple example:

```
F1[x_] := Log[x]
F2[x_] := Log[1 - x]
Table1 = Table[{F1[x], F2[x]}, {x, 0.01, 0.99, 0.01}]
F3[x_] := 0.6*Log[x]
F4[x_] := Log[1 - x] - 1.5
Table2 = Table[{F3[x], F4[x]}, {x, 0.01, 0.99, 0.01}];
dot1 = {Table2[[1]]}
dot2 = {Table2[[2]]};
dot3 = {Table2[[3]]};
ListLinePlot[{Table1, dot1, dot2, dot3}, Ticks -> {None}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {Min[Table1[[All, 1]]], Min[Table1[[All, 2]]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Frontier", "dot1", "dot2"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", Row[{F}]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Pink, {Black, Thickness[0.02]}, {Blue, 
    Thickness[0.02]}, {Red, Thickness[0.02]}}]
```

[image]
Instead of adding this dots manually as I did, is there a smarter way to call them in a loop or using a function that evaluates all possible values of `Table2`?

Comment: "all possible values of Table2" `Table2` has 99 points. If all are plotted, many will too close together to distinguish. So do really want that? And do you want a legend showing 99 points, each with own color?

Comment: Indeed in my example would not be good to plot all of the dots. But I would still want to know how to call the dots from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not at all sure I understand your question, but given what understanding I have, I recommend a different approach to incorporating the information you want to display into your plot. The approach I feel would be better involves using [`Callout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) for identifying plot elements. I also recommend using a labeled frame rather than labeled axes.

Because using full set points crowds the plot too much, I start by subsampling `Table2`.

```
pts = Table2[[1 ;; -1 ;; 10]];
n = Length[pts];
```

Next I build the callouts for the dots.

```
dots = Table[{Callout[pts[[i]], Row[{"dot", i}]]}, {i, n}];
```

Now I build the plot.

```
Labeled[
  Show[
    ListLinePlot[
      Callout[Table1, "Frontier", {-.5, -.5}],
      PlotStyle -> Pink,
      Frame -> True],
    ListPlot[dots],
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.06],
    ImageSize -> 450],
  {"x", "F"}, {Bottom, Left}]
```

[image: plot]

This plot shows all the information that you requested to be in the plot and shows it in a way that I think makes it easier for the viewer to absorb it than the way you described in your question.

Comment: That is great, @m_goldberg. That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!